# How to open email template from and excel web addin

Tags: typescript, office-js, office-addins

I have been working on a new addin that I want to retrieve data from Excel and put it into a word document, which is then attached to an email in Outlook.
What I was able to find was achievable by only using Power Automate but I want to keep everything centralized in the addin instead.
Is there a way to do this? can anybody point me to the right direction?
I am working with yoeman generator and the TaskPane Addin with React and typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but this is not feasible in an Office Add-in. Each add-in only "knows" about the particular Office app (Excel, Word, Outlook, etc.) that it is running in and only about the currently open document (with some limited exceptions). So, it cannot do the kind of cross-Office-app integration that you want.

Comment: Thank you, this is a little disappointing. It would have been nice to have an alternative to DOCx which is a library that can open word files in javascript. Hopefully this is something Microsoft will be able to implement in the future.